# Bug Resolution Time

Tags: mysql, bugzilla

We are using Bugzilla tool for Defect/Bug Tracking. Recently I got a requirement to frame a mysql query to capture Time between bug detection, fix, and verification(Will not measure time from bug introduction as that is too difficult to determine). Could you please help me out in framing the query?

So after doing some research, here is my understanding:
Bug creation date is `bugs.creation_ts`.

Bug resolution date is something like

```
SELECT bug_when 
FROM bugs_activity, fielddefs 
WHERE bug_id=? AND added=‘resolved’ 
AND fieldid = fielddefs.id 
AND fielddefs.name=‘resolution’
```

That is: use the `fielddefs` table to figure out the field ID of the resolution field, and the `bugs_activity` table to find the relevant update of that field on the bug of interest.

But it's not good enough simply to look at the time when the field was set: because there may be several rows for the bug.

So, I need help  in figuring out the exact logic for pulling respective dates for a bug i.e. Closed date of a bug, Assigned date of a bug, Verified date of a bug etc..

Comment: Please provide the structure of the table and some sample rows.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your kind reply,i don't know how to provide the table structure here, but I am referring this link http://www.ravenbrook.com/tool/bugzilla-schema/?action=single&version=3.2.3&view=View+schema

Comment: Hi all,Can some body help me on this

Comment: Actually, I am using this query for capturing Assigned date of Bug :Select bugs.bug_id, bugs_activity.bug_when as ' ASSIGNED’
from bugs 
left join bugs_activity on     bugs.bug_id = bugs_activity.bug_id
 and bugs_activity.fieldid=8    and bugs_activity.added=' ASSIGNED’
  and bugs_activity.bug_when = (select max(a.bug_when)   from bugs_activity a Where
                                                     a.bug_id = bugs.bug_id   and a.fieldid=8 and a.added=' ASSIGNED')

Comment: ANd for Capturing Resolved Date of Bug: I am using this Query:Select bugs.bug_id, bugs_activity.bug_when as 'Resolved'
from bugs left join bugs_activity on     bugs.bug_id = bugs_activity.bug_id and bugs_activity.fieldid=8    and bugs_activity.added='RESOLVED'
  and bugs_activity.bug_when = (select max(a.bug_when)   from bugs_activity a Where                                                 a.bug_id = bugs.bug_id   and a.fieldid=8 and a.added='RESOLVED')
So Can i achieve the how much time did the bug take from changing its status by doing Datediff between two dates i.e. Assignd dat & Resolved